# In hibernate4, Annotation @MapKey's targetElement property was replace by what?

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate4，Annotation @MapKey's targetElement property was replace by what?

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKey(targetElement = ProductAttribute.class)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.DELETE })
public Map<ProductAttribute, String> getProductAttributeMapStore() {
    return productAttributeMapStore;
}
```

Now，I upgrade my project's hibernate.jar from hibernate3 to hibernate4.1, intellJ alert targetElement can found.

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/MapKey.html), `org.hibernate.annotations.Mapkey`  annotation has been deprecated in favor of [javax.persistence.MapKeyColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyColumn.html).

According API documentation, attribute [targetElement](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/MapKey.html#targetElement%28%29) is deprecated, because:

> Only useful if the collection does not use generics

In this specific case using targetElement is repetitive, because type of the map key is already given via use of generics:

```
Map<ProductAttribute, String>
```

Comment: Is it correct to replace legancy `MapKey` with `javax.persistence.MapKeyColumn` in order to make the code compile correctly?

Comment: Another question: In hibernate4，Annotation @MapKey was replace by what?

Comment: Please take a look at my very similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307329/hibernate-4-what-should-replace-deprecated-mapkey-to-map-a-map-collection-whi